# Allowing a second form in class to draw on it

Tags: c#, windows, graphics, abstract-class

I'm trying to Creategraphics() in a second form in my project. I made this in my Form1 code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    Form f = new Form();
    Graphics g;
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    NotifyIcon ni1 = new NotifyIcon();
    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    g = f.CreateGraphics();
```

Then in my Button Click this happens:

```
    private void mclick(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedmc = (Button)o;
        Minecraft m = new Minecraft("Steve (Minecraft)", 2011, "Juego en primera y tercera persona", "Velocidad, resistencia al fuego, variado...");
        m.DrawingAction(f, g);
        ni1.Visible = true;
        ni1.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
        ni1.ShowBalloonTip(10, "Minecraft", m.Summary(), ToolTipIcon.None);

        this.Invalidate();
        this.Visible = false;
    }
```

this is the reference in class:

```
    public override void DrawingAction(Form f, Graphics g)
    {
        f.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(close);

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

        f.Visible = true;
        f.Width = 600;
        f.Height = 400;
        f.MaximizeBox = false;
        f.MinimizeBox = false;

        g.DrawLine(pen, 100, 100, 200, 200);

    }
```

But the Second Form does everything else, except drawing. Do I need to add a property to "f" before drawing??

I add the answers. I took the reference Dour gave me in the comment :P

public override void DrawingAction(Form f, PictureBox p)
        {
            f.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(close);
            p.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(paint);

```
        //Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

        f.Visible = true;
        f.Width = 600;
        f.Height = 400;
        f.MaximizeBox = false;
        f.MinimizeBox = false;

        p.Visible = true;
        p.Enabled = true;
        p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        p.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
        p.BringToFront();
        p.Image = Image.FromFile("h.png"); //This image is perfect to fit in a corner of the form, I will add it to Paint event to redraw it everytime I make another drawing :P 


    }

    //
    private void close(Object o, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Visible = true;
    }
    private void paint(Object o, PaintEventArgs P)
    {
        Graphics g = P.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 100, 100, 200, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: g is null in your post.  Not very clear what you are trying to draw on.  Your graphic object should be coming from an image or a paint event of a control.  Avoid CreateGraphics, it's only a temp drawing that gets easily erased.

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry, I forgot to add g = f.CreateGraphics();
I know it's temporal and ca be erased easily, but I can´t draw anything. I'm trying to draw a line just in the form to test it but wont do it lol

Comment: You're not drawing a line to your form, you're drawing it to a temporary object `g` that you never display or do anything with. If you're trying to draw to your form you need to draw in your `Paint` event handler.

Comment: If you solved your own question, you should post the solution as an answer and, if no better one has been posted for a few days, accept it. That will mark your question as answered and will even give you a new participation badge. Also, `DrawingAction` should be called in your form constructor not from a Click event.

Comment: @DourHighArch No, I created the controls in the main Form, I just send them, I don't really see it necessary. And Yes, i want to show your comment, how Do it select it as answers? I'm too noob at this page lol

Comment: Don't select comments as answers; answers should be useful for others who search for the same problem. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23706117/edit) your question, cut the solution code from your question and paste it into the big “Your Answer” text field below. After a day or so you can check your own post as the solution.